# Pinless moisture meter

Tags: capacitance

How does capacitance in a non invasive moisture meter work? I know an AC voltage is transmitted into the capacitor and that the dielectric is affected by moisture, but how do these all work together to determine moisture? I believe there is a RF field as well - but is this the electric field induced by the capacitor?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of the instrument you are thinking of? There are a variety of moisture sensors out there...

Comment: just added photo!

Answer (score 0):

It's basically just a matter of calibration. Somebody has to measure the capacitance of the sensor for different moisture levels in the lab and that's the calibration curve that one can use in the field to translate capacitance back to moisture. How does one measure capacitance precisely? Usually by making the capacitor part of an LC or RC oscillator and by measuring the oscillation frequency. That is extremely sensitive, precise and also very simple and cheap.